# Travelling to Iceland and UK

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, iceland

We will be travelling to the UK (holding valid multiple entry visa) and to Iceland with a Schengen visa. Can we visit the UK first and then travel from London to Iceland?

Answer (score 10):

If you have visas for both places, then yes, of course you can travel between them. That's what the visas are for.

In particular, there is **no rule** requiring that you must arrive in Iceland directly from the country where you filed your visa application.